# All iOS screen size compatibility?

Tags: ios, compatibility, viewcontroller

New to iOS developing here. Basically I am creating a soundboard app. I have the app essentially working (aka buttons returning sounds).

However my app only looks proper on the iPhone 6. I just have one ViewController in my main storyboard. When I run the simulator for the 4S/5/6+ or iPads, my buttons are pretty much everywhere.

I tried playing with size classes/autolayout through Apple's documentation, but couldn't get it working properly. What's the best (easiest ;) ) route I can follow to have it basically looking the same on ALL devices?

PS: I have one background placed too, I don't mind if it looks different on all devices since it's pretty minimalistic, but if someone can shed some light here too, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503). It covers all of this.

Comment: The [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853) would be real useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1) Continue your plan spending time getting friendly with Auto Layout and Size Classes. This might be difficult at first, but it will really pay off later. You should use the Assistant Editor's Preview mode to let you see iPhone 4, 5 and 6 side-by-side as you work so you can make sure your layouts look great everywhere.

2) Use a component like `UIStackView` where layouts are automatically adjusted to fit various devices. If your soundboard is as simple as a grid of buttons, you can do that in just a few minutes using a stack view.

3) Use a component like `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` where content is designed to scroll. Using this method you design only one sound button of your app (i.e., enough to play one sound) then have iOS replicate that across all the sounds you want. When your interface is presented on a device of a different size iOS will just make the content scroll.

Very roughly, option 1 makes you do all the work; option 2 makes your layout shrink down until it fits the available space; and option 3 makes your layout stay the same size no matter what, but you should expect it to scroll on some devices.

There is no right solution; it's entirely down how you want your app to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what the deployment target of the OP is, however, it is important to note that UIStackView is only available in iOS 9+